# Upload profile photo to salecforce via jsforce

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsforce

I want to upload profile photo to salecforce via jsforce,
but for some reason I can't using this code

````
  let fileOnServer = "./files/photo.jpg", // static photo url
    fileName = "Contact Picture",
    fileType = "image/jpeg";
  fs.readFile(fileOnServer, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(404).send({ errorMessage: err });
    } else {
      let base64data = new Buffer(data).toString("base64");
      JSFORCE_CONNECTION.sobject("Attachment").create(
        {
          ParentId: "0034K000004ZpFcQAK",
          Name: fileName,
          Body: base64data,
          ContentType: fileType,
        },
        function (err, ret) {
          if (err || !ret.success) {
            res.send("error");
            return console.error("error", err, ret);
          }
          console.log("Created Successfully : " + ret.id, ret);
          res.send("created");
        }
      );
    }
  });
};```
````

Comment: Errors in console? On server?

Comment: is loading but the profile photo is not changing

Comment: Cache? Reload page?

Comment: i don't know what profile photo upload

Comment: Did you get the code from here: https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/43 ?

Comment: Why not ask this question here:  [salesforce stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=profile+picture)

Comment: I also copied my code from this code =>https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/43